# Cannot build graph with Dagger 2

Tags: java, dependency-injection, annotations, dagger, dagger-2

I am trying to create the dependency graph with Dagger 2 based on the example of the dagger 2 website (the coffeeMaker and the source is here : https://github.com/google/dagger/tree/master/examples/simple).

I created the component as stated in the site :

```
@Component(modules = {DripCoffeeModule.class})
public interface CoffeeShop {
    CoffeeMaker maker();
}
```

The annotation processor correctly generates the files (in the target directory) but I am unable to find the `DaggerCoffeeShop` class. (Ctrl + space) does not work.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those generated files are usually placed in the target folder of your project (fe: `myProject/target/generated-sources/annotations/my/package/DaggerCoffeeShop.java`). So you just have to indicate to your IDE that the `annotations` folder is a source folder.

- [Intellij](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/sources-tab.html)
- Eclipse: `Project > Properties > Java Build Path > Source > Add Folder`